# What is happening with my MAC address when connecting my pc to the internet?

Tags: networking, router, mac-address

I want to understand how my MAC address gets shared with others (router, other devices from the local internet). Is it in the internet packet which gets send... and when? Is there a way to interfere with this?
With this knowledge I want to design something with two ethernet ports (input and output) which is able to change the used mac address to one I specified.

Comment: Your MAC address only gets shared with other devices on the same layer 2 network - which in most cases means within the local network in your house. Your router will get your MAC address when it attempts to forward a packet to your PC.

Comment: In short, MAC addresses never leave the building - which makes spoofing them rather pointless for a desktop or fixed system. Many mobile devices randomise their MAC if connecting to unfamiliar wifi networks, but stop randomising once known.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to aggregate two ethernet ports together? This is usually called nic teaming (or bonding), and can be set up in whatever operating system without too much trouble. Here's an example for windows (server), which has a gui for it: https://woshub.com/configure-nic-teaming-windows/

Comment: I believe the concept you are looking to understand is called **arp resolution** - Which is the process by whivh devices on a LAN segment discover each other.  When a device knows it needs to speak to another device in the same subnet it briadcasts an ARP request to all devices in the subnet.  The one that has it responds.  ARP entries typically time out after a while (not sure how long - a few minutes I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer puts its own MAC address as the Ethernet source address in the Ethernet-layer headers on every Ethernet frame it sends across the Ethernet LAN.

When other devices on the network need to send Ethernet frames to your computer, they need to know your computer's Ethernet MAC address in order to address those Ethernet frames.

If something on your Ethernet LAN, such as your router, has an IP datagram it needs to send (forward) to your computer's IP address, then it uses the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) to ask who (i.e. which MAC address) has the destination IP address in question. So the device that's trying to learn your MAC address broadcasts out an ARP "who-has" query asking basically "What is the MAC address associated with this IP address?", and your computer responds with a unicast ARP "is-at" response, answering the question with its own MAC address. Now the device that was trying to send that IP datagram is able to successfully fill in the Ethernet destination MAC address in the Ethernet frame headers, so it can plop that IP datagram into an Ethernet frame and send it across the Ethernet LAN to your computer.